# Justification for wrapping constructor with a regular function?

Tags: oop

At another forum I've came across the argument about some corner case of using constructors and I remembered reading somewhere that it would be considered a good design to forbid code outside the class' own sandbox to call that class' constructor. The argument was related to invoking a superclass constructor defined to accept variable number of arguments, while the particular language in question doesn't allow funcalling the constructor in general.

I don't remember who said that and on what occasion, but I have a feeling it was some respectful source, although, my memory may betray me. Language specifics aside, would this make sense as a meta-language good practice, or is this just a made-up rule / too personal to be a generic recommendation?

Below are some justification I could think of:

1. Regardless of the language, there are typically problems with initialization order, which is usually peculiar to the object being created, outside code might not be aware of these particularities / exposing these particularities may be considered as leaking the detail of implementation of the object.
2. Errors inside constructor pose a difficulty in languages w/o automatic memory management. Letting outside code manage such errors is an almost guaranteed failure / memory leak.
3. Inheritance often times requires that we both be able to reference subclass from superclass (anonymously, by, for example, calling an abstract method - think of Java, where this is problematic) and back (not necessarily anonymously). I.e. if a superclass calls a function on its fields, we may need to pre-initialize those fields to certain other values in the subclass, and, certainly, we might need to use the product of superclass initialization in the subclass. This might require to have "hooks" into constructor, but would not be possible, if we expose the "bare" constructor to outside code (as the outside code may affect the object creation in such case by working outside of convention) on what is being initialized and when.

Answer (score 0):

What you're referring to is generally called a *static factory method*, an alternative to calling the constructor directly. Whether or not this is good design depends on the use case.

Calling constructors directly is generally preferred because it is the natural way of creating objects, however there are many situations where a factory method is preferred. This post on MSDN is an excellent summary of when to use one over the other: [Factories vs. Constructors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2004/10/11/241027.aspx)

I don't think I have come across the superclass argument you mentioned though.

Comment: @wvxvw: You're right, but even if `make-instance` isn't technically a "constructor", it would be familiar to most users in that language, just like `new` in other languages, and I think that is a big enough advantage to stick to it unless you really need a different method.